# Java method returning a java.lang.Class<? extends T> for passing into generics

Tags: java, generics, refactoring

I have these lines of code.

```java
private void DoSomethingOnThePage(int pageNo){
  List<T> result = null;

  if(pageNo == 1)
    result  = Checker.Load(input,  pageNo, CheckResultA.class);
  else if(pageNo == 2)
    result  = Checker.Load(input,  pageNo, CheckResultB.class);
  else if(pageNo == 3)
    result = Checker.Load(input,  pageNo, CheckResultC.class);
  else if(pageNo == 4)
    result = Checker.Load(input,  pageNo, CheckResultD.class);

  // do something else with the result ....
}
```

I am trying to extract a method for those condition to be like this.
so that i can have a cleaner view to see the workflow in my code.

```java
private java.lang.Class<? extends T> GetClassTypeByPageNo(int pageNo){
  if(pageNo == 1)
    return CheckResultA.class;
  else if(pageNo == 2)
    return CheckResultB.class;
  else if(pageNo == 3)
    return CheckResultC.class
  else if(pageNo == 4)
    return CheckResultD.class
  else 
    return CheckResultBase.class;
}

private void DoSomethingOnThePage(int pageNo){

  result = Checker.Load(input,  pageNo, GetClassTypeByPageNo(pageNo));

  // do something else with the result ....
}
```

I have tried a lot of ways but fail to find a correct way so that i can compile.

Can Java do this and how to do it?

Or is there better way to do this?

Thank you.

Signature of Checker.Load

```java
private static <T extends CheckResultBase> List<T> Load(byte[] input, int pageNo, java.lang.Class<? extends T> type){
  // load something in to the List
}
```

Comment: It looks like you could just return `Class<?>` and not worry about the `T` as you don't restrict it anyway. What is the signature of `Checker.load` and what's the type of `result`?

Comment: Where is that `T` coming from? Is it declared on the class like `class YourClass<T>`, if not you would have to declare it on the method: `private <T> Class<? extends T> GetClassTypeByPageNo(int pageNo)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the method returning the class as generic without type T,

```
private java.lang.Class<?> GetClassTypeByPageNo(int pageNo){
      if(pageNo == 1)
        return CheckResultA.class;
      else if(pageNo == 2)
        return CheckResultB.class;
      else if(pageNo == 3)
        return CheckResultC.class;
      else if(pageNo == 4)
        return CheckResultD.class;
      else 
        return CheckResultBase.class;
    }
```

or may be something like,

```
private java.lang.Class<? extends CheckResultBase> GetClassTypeByPageNo(int pageNo){
```

assuming all your `CheckResultXXX` classes extend the `CheckResultBase` class and you want this method to have type restricted return value.